# Is it possible to reduce the actions of document.createElement and appendChild into one command in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an object that creating an instance of it would act like document.createElement(), with the added benefit that classes would be able to extend from it, plus pass to it a parent element that it would automatically appendChild itself to.

For example:

```
class Player extends Model {
 constructor(parent, att0, att1) {
  super(parent, "div");
  
  let attribute0 = new Model(this, "h5");
  let attribute1 = new Model(this, "h5");
  
  attribute0.innerText = att0;
  attribute1.innerText = att1;
 }
}
```

Instead of:

```
class Player{
 constructor(att0, att1) {
  
  let attribute0 = document.createElement("h5");
  let attribute1 = document.createElement("h5");
  
  attribute0.innerText = att0;
  attribute1.innerText = att1;

  this.appendChild(attribute0);
  this.appendChild(attribute1);
 }
}
```

(And appending Player instances as children to their parent class)

Is this possible to do? If so, how and what's the best way to implement it? If not, is there at least similar I could do to achieve a similar result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So make a function that creates and appends and returns the element....It is going to be 2 steps to make an element and append.

Comment: Yes, but I also want to be able to able to appendChild classes that extend Model (e.g. Player) to other elements and classes

Answer (score 0):

The web actually supports custom elements, you can do:

```js
class Player extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor() {
    this.appendChild(document.createElement('h2'));
    this.lastElementChild.textContent = this.dataset.title;
    this.appendChild(document.createElement('h4'));
    this.lastElementChild.textContent = this.dataset.subtitle;
  }
}
customElements.define('player-wrapper', Player, { extends: 'div' });
```

And then render it with:

```html
<player-wrapper subtitle='foo' title='bar' />
```

You can read about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

You can also take children as attributes etc though declarative composition is usually done in the templates which are supported anyway.

Typically - people just use some component system like Angular/React/Vue for this though rather than using "raw" web components.

Comment: As for your 'literal' question - `createElement` returns the element so you can do `this.appendChild(document.createElement('h5'))` and appendChild in turn returns the child. So `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('h5')).innerHTML='hello'` works

Comment: I'd really rather not use custom elements and I'd like to use identifiers instead of this.lastElementChild, besides, this solution does not address how to make it so classes (like Player in my example) could also be appended as children to a parent class/element through their constructor